# NUnit 3 - TestCase doesn't validate ExpectedResult even if they're 'equal'

Tags: .net, nunit

I tried to look on already answered questions and none of them sounds familiar to my case so I'm opening this thread.

I'm using NUnit 3 under VS 2015 and after unit-testing a project I realized something gone wrong. The expected result, in fact, is 'equal' (not on reference but by value) to what I've expecting to receive but NUnit didn't validate it.

Is intendend?

Below the code to run the test.

```
public static class DataFactory
{
    public static class Dummy
    {
        public static string ContractUrl = "";

        public static IEnumerable Objects
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(ContractUrl, true, false).Returns(false);
                yield return new TestCaseData(ContractUrl, "", "Ciao").Returns("Ciao");
                yield return new TestCaseData(ContractUrl, Payload.Dummy.TrueRequest, Payload.Dummy.TrueResponse).Returns(Payload.Dummy.TrueResponse);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Payload
{
    public static class Dummy
    {
        public static GetItemsRequest TrueRequest
        {
            get
            {
                return new GetItemsRequest() { };
            }
        }

        public static GetItemsResponse TrueResponse
        {
            get
            {
                return new GetItemsResponse()
                {
                    Result = true
                };
            }
        }
    }
}


[DataContract]
public class GetItemsRequest : ICloneable<GetItemsRequest>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string QuoteCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int QuoteRevision { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DocumentFormat Format { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Description("Nel caso sia False devo inizializzare l'ambiente, ovvero scaricare tutti i documenti in tutte le lingue." +
                 "Viene pilotato dal CRM, che setta a False o True la property nel Request Payload.")]
    public bool GetContent { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Description("Viene usato per indicare se nel GetContent deve essere passato il percorso del documento "+
                 "(GetRemotePath = true) oppure il contenuto del documento.")]
    public bool GetRemotePath { get; set; }

    //Language Code
    [DataMember]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    public GetItemsRequest Clone()
    {
        return (GetItemsRequest)Cloning.DeepCopy(this);
    }
}


[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PositionCode { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class GetItemsResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Result { get; set; }

    [Description("Messaggio d'errore. Si presenta solo se Result = false.")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<TDSContent> Contents { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TDSContent : Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TextContent { get; set; }
}
```

And the Unit Test

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(DataFactory.Dummy), "Objects")]
    public object Dummy(string contractUrl, object payload, object expectedResult)
    {
        return expectedResult;
    }
```

Which gives the following results:

[image]

Is this the expected behavior?
Is the Expected Result must match on reference instead by value?

Comment: To override the default behavior for comparison this page could help:

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Custom-Constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing against a type that NUnit knows nothing about, `GetItemsRequest`, ultimately it's just calling that class's `Equals` method (that it inherits from `object`).  [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx), if you didn't override it in your class then it will use reference equality for classes and a slightly more complex way for value types.

---

Let's look deep into the bowels of NUnit to verify this.  Down in `TestMethodCommand.Execute()`, [you'll see this code](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/65f0b974cb65a6588a54de96f0ce929f57e39f59/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Commands/TestMethodCommand.cs#L63):

```
public override TestResult Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
{    
    // TODO: Decide if we should handle exceptions here
    object result = RunTestMethod(context);

    if (testMethod.HasExpectedResult)
        NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(testMethod.ExpectedResult, result);

    context.CurrentResult.SetResult(ResultState.Success);
    // TODO: Set assert count here?
    //context.CurrentResult.AssertCount = context.AssertCount;
    return context.CurrentResult;
}
```

This is the code that ultimately invokes your test method (inside of `RunTestMethod`).  As you can see, it takes the return value of your method and passes it into `Assert.AreEqual()`.  This assertion [looks like this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/65f0b974cb65a6588a54de96f0ce929f57e39f59/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Assert.Equality.cs#L126):

```
public static void AreEqual(object expected, object actual)
{
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected), null, null);
}
```

[`Is.EqualTo`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/65f0b974cb65a6588a54de96f0ce929f57e39f59/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Is.cs#L207) just creates an `EqualConstraint`, whose [`Apply` method looks like this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/65f0b974cb65a6588a54de96f0ce929f57e39f59/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/EqualConstraint.cs#L372):

```
public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(TActual actual)
{
    AdjustArgumentIfNeeded(ref actual);
    return new EqualConstraintResult(this, actual, 
        _comparer.AreEqual(_expected, actual, ref _tolerance));
}
```

The `_comparer` reference by default (which it would be in your case since you didn't specify a different one) is the `NUnitEqualityComparer`, and the relevant part of its [`AreEqual` method looks like this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/65f0b974cb65a6588a54de96f0ce929f57e39f59/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/NUnitEqualityComparer.cs#L134):

```
public bool AreEqual(object x, object y, ref Tolerance tolerance)
{
    if (x == null && y == null)
        return true;

    if (x == null || y == null)
        return false;

    if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        return true;

    // Omitted: a whole bunch of checks for specific types that will fail in your case.

    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

That last line there is where the actual comparison occurs.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.
In fact to validate a result I use a custom object comparer.

I wish it could be possibile to override the method ApplyTo, using my custom comparer.

That 'override' in the code sounds good:

public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(TActual actual)
{
    AdjustArgumentIfNeeded(ref actual);
    return new EqualConstraintResult(this, actual, 
        _comparer.AreEqual(_expected, actual, ref _tolerance));
}

Comment: Could you point me in right direction how to override it? It seems it couldn't be done.

Comment: I don't see a way to specify a custom comparer when using `TestCaseData`.  If you were writing the assertion yourself, you'd typically write `Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected).Using(yourComparer))`.  Since the framework runs that assertion instead, and there's way to specify that comparer, I think you'd have to rewrite your test.

Comment: I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1794) to hopefully address this.

Answer (score 3):

This is only indirectly related to reference equality. As you will note with the case of `false` the test works perfectly well for value objects.

NUnit uses an `EqualConstraint` to compare the returned result to the expected result. Hence, no comparison will succeed unless they would also work with `Assert.AreEqual` in your own code.

In this case, you have not overridden the Equals method for your class. Therefore, the underlying `object.Equals` method is used. That's where reference equality comes in, since that's what is implemented by `object`.

Comment: Hi Charlie,
I've seen your reply on NUnit thread and I've some questions for you, if you mind to help.